# UIAppearance proxy caching appearance between compile times?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

I'm using the the new UIAppearance API and have successfully set the tint color for all UINavigationBar and UIToolbar instances via my AppDelegate like so...

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    UIColor *tint = [UIColor colorWithRed:212 green:63 blue:69 alpha:1.0];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:tint];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:tint];
}
```

However, if I change the RGB value and re-build/run, the toolbars and nab bars all turn white, no matter what color I set it to!

It's as though the proxy is caching somewhere. When I delete the app, and then reinstall, the RGB values appear as they should, until I change them and rebuild again.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:

Now, I've noticed, it will arbitrarily switch to a white background between compile times without even changing the RGB. *(NOTE: The RGB above should return a reddish tint.)*

UPDATE 2:

My darling fiancée happened to be looking over my shoulder and noticed that in my test cases, the problem only seemed to occur when I had values in more than one RGB channel at a time.

For example:

```
UIColor *tint = [UIColor colorWithRed:212 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
```

worked, whereas

```
UIColor *tint = [UIColor colorWithRed:212 green:63 blue:69 alpha:1.0];
```

would not.

**The solution?**

Use `colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:]` takes a set of floats from `0.0f` to `1.0f`. You're passing in a set of integers.